# VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [helper]

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-ec2

In order for users to register for my website, the registration form requires email, physical address, zip code, and password. I have two separate ways to run my app -- using dev_manage.py, which runs the app on localhost using a SQLite DB, and manage.py, which is hosted on an EC2 instance and uses a PostgreSQL DB.

The catch is, when I'm on my localhost the registration form works *perfectly*, and it stores email, address, zip code and password appropriately in the SQLite DB. However, on the live EC2 version of the app, I get a VariableDoesNotExist error from using a crispy_forms helper, which for some reason is trying to require only email and password. The helper layout, on the other hand, is trying to force email, address, zip code and password. Also, if I remove the 'helper' from the template tag, then the localhost registration form still asks for email, address, zip code and password, while the EC2 registration form no longer gives me a  VariableDoesNotExist error but only asks for email and password.

Interestingly, the only differences between dev.py and settings.py are the databases each version uses:

**dev.py** (which is called in dev_manage.py):

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import logging, os
import logging.handlers

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1:8000']

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # Django Apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # My Apps
    'cart',
    'recipes',
    'djangoratings',
    'registration',
    'customer_profile',
    'stripe',
    # Third Party Apps
    'crispy_forms',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'foodshop.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'foodshop.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static_root")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_in_pro", "our_static"),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "media_root")

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'

#DJANGO REGISTRATION REDUX SETTINGS
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN = True
SITE_ID = 1
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/menu'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'customer_profile.MyUser'
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
```

**settings.py** (which is called in manage.py):

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import logging, os
import logging.handlers

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXX'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'XXXXXXXXXX'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # Django Apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # My Apps
    'cart',
    'recipes',
    'djangoratings',
    'registration',
    'customer_profile',
    'stripe',
    # Third Party Apps
    'crispy_forms',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'foodshop.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'foodshop.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {    
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'XXXXXXXXXX',
        'USER' : 'XXXXXXXXXX',
        'PASSWORD' : 'XXXXXXXXXX',
        'HOST' : 'XXXXXXXXXX.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT' : '5432',
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static_root")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_in_pro", "our_static"),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "media_root")

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'

#DJANGO REGISTRATION REDUX SETTINGS
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN = True
SITE_ID = 1
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/menu'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'customer_profile.MyUser'
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXX"
```

Additionally, I have dropped the schema, removed all migrations, and re-migrated -- essentially starting from scratch. The necessary tables and columns exist, the schema looks correct, and I am connected to the PostgreSQL DB.

In case these are helpful...

**registration.forms.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals


from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit, Layout, Field

from .users import UserModel, UsernameField

User = UserModel()


class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    """
    Form for registering a new user account.

    Validates that the requested username is not already in use, and
    requires the password to be entered twice to catch typos.

    Subclasses should feel free to add any additional validation they
    need, but should avoid defining a ``save()`` method -- the actual
    saving of collected user data is delegated to the active
    registration backend.

    """
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label='E-mail')
    address = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Street Address')
    zip_code = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Zip Code')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'address', 'zip_code', 'password1', 'password2')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-exampleForm'
        self.helper.form_class = 'blueForms'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = 'submit_survey'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Create Account', css_class='btn btn-lg btn-primary'))

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('email', placeholder='E-mail'),
            Field('address', placeholder='Street Address'),
            Field('zip_code', placeholder='Zip Code'),
            Field('password1', placeholder='Password'),
            Field('password2', placeholder='Confirm Password'),
        )
```

**registration.users.py**

```
from django.conf import settings

from .compat import get_model

try:
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    UserModel = get_user_model
except ImportError:
    UserModel = lambda: get_model('auth', 'User')


def UserModelString():
    try:
        return settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    except AttributeError:
        return 'auth.User'

def UsernameField():
    return getattr(UserModel(), 'USERNAME_FIELD', 'email')
```

I'm completely stumped. How could everything work exactly as intended on a localhost but not on my EC2 instance? Have I forgotten or missed a certain step? Also, please let me know if any other snippets of code would be useful to help troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

After days of scrutinizing my code, I just discovered the root cause. I had django-registration-redux installed, and doing pip uninstall django-registration-redux fixed the issue. I'm not entirely sure of the technical reasons behind why this would have caused problems, but this same problem was affecting other apps I had built too.